# Using different row values to create a function

Tags: r, dataset

I'm using the sp500 dataset to produce some visualizations and i'm trying to figure out how to code the formula for the daily returns.
With 't' being the day in question, I've figured out the formula but I can't conceptualize how to get it into R code. The formula is

(ClosingPrice(T)-ClosingPrice(T-1))/ClosingPrice(T-1)

I'm not sure how to reference the column that precedes the one in question (ClosingPrice[-1]?) but I need to make it into a function which I'll use to iterate through the rows, the value of which will go into the new column sp500$DailyReturns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be more an R programming problem than a statistics problem, but
sometimes the line between the two is fuzzy, so here goes.
If I understand the problem correctly, I believe the following R code will
give you a clue how to handle this.

My vector `cp` has 20 fake closing prices (with a bit of an upward trend), `dif.cp` has differences (with a `NA` for the first element), and `dr` is the daily return. Notice that output of `diff` is
a vector one element shorter than its argument. [Use the same `set.seed`
statement for exactly the same fake data; omit or set a different seed for
your own fresh example.]

```
set.seed(1883)
t = 1:20;  cp = round(rnorm(20, 100, 5)) + 2*t
dif.cp = c(NA, diff(cp))
dr = c(NA, diff(cp))/cp
cbind(cp,dif.cp, dr)  # binds together column vectors to make matrix
       cp dif.cp           dr
 [1,] 104     NA           NA
 [2,] 106      2  0.018867925
 [3,] 106      0  0.000000000
 [4,] 112      6  0.053571429
 [5,] 119      7  0.058823529
 [6,] 107    -12 -0.112149533
 [7,] 108      1  0.009259259
 [8,] 112      4  0.035714286
 [9,] 116      4  0.034482759
[10,] 127     11  0.086614173
[11,] 115    -12 -0.104347826
[12,] 127     12  0.094488189
[13,] 118     -9 -0.076271186
[14,] 126      8  0.063492063
[15,] 128      2  0.015625000
[16,] 131      3  0.022900763
[17,] 131      0  0.000000000
[18,] 131      0  0.000000000
[19,] 141     10  0.070921986
[20,] 139     -2 -0.014388489
```

You may have to make slight adjustments to fit your needs exactly. And maybe someone else has a stunning more clever way to do this.